# Use data from mongodb backup in rails app... i.e. convert BSON to JSON using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongodb, bson

I have a bunch of data from a mongodb backup that I'd like to import into a new rails app (was developing using mongo, now switching back to activerecord).

I've tried the obvious `BSON.deserialize(doc)` but it only returns the first record. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is there an easy way to convert BSON files to JSON or another usable format for bringing into MySQL?

Edit: Well, this is hardly the best way, I'm sure... but I've managed to convert them using a ruby shell script (utilizing `bsondump`, a part of mongodb).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

bson_files = Dir['./*.bson']

bson_files.each do |file|
  tmp_file_name = file+".tmp"
  new_file_name = file+".json"

  system("bsondump "+file+" > "+tmp_file_name)
  file = File.open(tmp_file_name)
  contents = []
  file.each {|line| contents << line }
  contents = "["+contents[0..-2].join.gsub(/}\n/,"},\n")[0..-3].gsub(/ObjectId\( (.{26}) \)/,"\\1").gsub(/Date\( ([0-9]*) \)/,"\\1")+"]"
  out = File.open(new_file_name, 'w')
  out.write(contents)
end
```

better solutions are still appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any form of nesting, your current script will start falling apart.

Honestly, your best bet is simply to re-create the MongoDB locally and then run a script to read from that DB and output back to the MySQL. Basically just pull the objects from MongoDB and map them into your ActiveRecord objects so that you can save them.

You will need to create your new objects anyways, so here's a great way to test out your schema.

Answer (score 0):

bson object have a method named [to_json](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/bson-ruby/BSON/JSON)